# Deduplicating a list while keeping its order, and OrderedSet?

Tags: python, list, duplicates, ordereddict

Given a list as follows, deduplicating the list without concern for order, we can do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x = [1,2,3,9,8,3,2,5,3,2,7,3,6,7]

list(set(x)) # Outputs: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If we want to keep the order, we can do something like:

```
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)) # Outputs: [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 5, 7, 6]
```

Using `OrderedDict.fromkeys`, then casting it into a list again is kept of cumbersome. And seem counter-intuitive but I suppose there's some reason for Python dev to decide on processing sets with ordering as dictionary instead.

### Is there such an object as `OrderedSet` that can achieve the same deduplication while keeping order?

If there isn't, what is the motivation to support `OrderedDict` but not `OrderedSet`? Is it an anti-pattern to create a custom object like `OrderedSet`?

Comment: From Python 3.6+ you do not need to use OrderedDict since dict now keeps insertion order. `list({}.fromkeys(x))`

Comment: The dupe doesn't make sense @dawg. It's correct to observe that dictionary insertion order is preserved but it's not clear why it wasn't extended to sets

Comment: @roganjosh: If it is not a dup, it is kinda opinion. I reopened to let others decide.

Comment: I agree with the opinion side but I think it's explained in https://youtu.be/p33CVV29OG8 . I don't have chance right now to watch it to refamiliarise myself with it. I think he explains it somewhere in there, and there'll be a PEP somewhere